# is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc

Tags: drupal-7

I have enable the s3fs module and I have getting following warning message during drush clear cache:
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc

here the details(web-server Nginx and OS is Ubuntu):

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-xx-xxx$ drush cc
Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
[0] : Cancel
[1] : all
[2] : drush
[3] : theme-registry
[4] : menu
[5] : css-js
[6] : block
[7] : module-list
[8] : theme-list
[9] : registry
[10] : advagg
[11] : libraries
[12] : token
[13] : views

1
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:2144 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:2144 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:2144 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:2144 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:439 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:439 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:439 [warning]
is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? file.inc:439 [warning]
WD php: Error: Call to a member function getDirectoryPath() on boolean in image_menu() (line 83 of [error]
/xxxx/xxxx/public_html/modules/image/image.module).
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the case for every instance of this error, but I was getting this when I was syncing a site from a production server to my local environment. Turned out it was my temporary file path being invalid causing the issue. Was able to fix it quickly via drush: `drush vset file_temporary_path /tmp`.